# How can I control HSV value using material nodes?

Tags: materials, shader-nodes

I have this file where a few different materials have the same base color. I'm trying to find a way to change just the Hue on all materials at the same time.

I tried plugging a Combine HSV node into the Base Color, and then a Value node but I can't figure out a way to change the Hue value using a central controller that affects all materials... Is there a simple way to do so?

Comment: Is it for rendering or for baking ?

Comment: @Gorgious for rendering... but does it make a difference?

Comment: If it's for rendering you can change the hue very easily in the compositor workspace

Comment: @Gorgious ooh of course! I was just thinking if there was a way to control it before the render stage

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The easiest trick for having a setting that controls the same value in multiple materials is to put the value in a [*Node Group*](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/interface/controls/nodes/groups.html) and share it among the materials.

Any change you make inside the node group is shared by every user of that group.

To use a Combine HSV node as the control in the Node editor:

- Create a material
- Add a Combine HSV node
- Select the Combine HSV node and *Make Node Group* (shortcut <kbd>CTRL</kbd>–<kbd>G</kbd>)
- Disconnect the H input from the HSV.  This means you share H among all of the materials using the group but each has its own S and V  You'll end up with something like this:

  [image: Node group showing Hue separated]
- Close the node group (Shortcut <kbd>Tab</kbd>)
- Connect the *Color* output from the new node group to the shader:

  [image: Shader with color from node group]

Having done this, you can now add the node group to your materials with the usual add command (shortcut <kbd>Shift</kbd>–<kbd>A</kbd>).  It will show up in the *group* submenu:

[image: Add menu showing node group]

Now, when you want to change the Hue, select any material, open the node group (select it and shortcut <kbd>Tab</kbd>) and make your change.

You should give your node group a unique name to make it easier to find in the menu and delete the H input you're not using.

To delete the input:

- Select the Node group
- <kbd>Tab</kbd> to open it for editing.
- Open the sidebar if it's not open (Shortcut <kbd>N</kbd>
- Go to the group tab
- Go to the inputs drop down.
- Select each input in turn and click on the minus button
  [image: Group tab showing H input ready for deletion]

Comment: Good one, but you got it reversed: I want the same Hue with different SV for each material, so instead I just connected the S and V inputs to the Combine HSV node, and deleted the H. If you edit it with these changes I'll accept your answer.

Comment: @Luciano  Oops. Sorry for not reading your question more carefully.  Thanks for pointing that out.  Answer edited.